# c# - How to split a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split string preserving whole words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398270/how-to-split-string-preserving-whole-words)

I have the following string:

```
string s = "The Electors shall meet in their respective states to vote by ballot for President and Vice-President.";
```

I want to take the first 60 characters and split them into two separate strings each of 30 characters or less. Each string must start with a whole word (no partial word, nor space). So this is the desired result:

```
string s1 = "The Electors shall meet in"; // 26 characters
string s2 = "their respective states to vot"; // 30 characters
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398270/how-to-split-string-preserving-whole-words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "The Electors shall meet in their respective states to vote by ballot for President and Vice-President.";

string sSub = s.Substring(0,60);  //first 60 letters

string sSubSub = sSub.Substring(0,30);  //at most 30 per string

int index = sSubSub.LastIndexOf(' '); //finds the last space

string firstString = sSub.Substring(0,index); //first string is up until that space of t he 60-letter string

string secondSTring = sSub.Substring(index + 1, 30); //second string is the first 30 letters of the rest of the 60-letter string
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Just changed secondString to `sSub.Substring(index+1, 30);`

Comment: @user1481183 Oh, yeah, whoops. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calculating the midpoint then work in both directions until you find a space. That would then be your splitting point.