# Split a text with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to get a text splitted with regex in  Java (each substring will be less than or close to 10 characters (including space and special) and no word would be splitted). For example, "James has gone out for a meal." would be "James has", "gone out", "for a meal", ".". 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried Splitter in Guava like Splitter.on(regexp).trimResults().split(text). For regexp I've used something like "(\W|^)[\w.]{0,10} (\W|$)". I guess it is logically incorrect.

Comment: You can derive some inspiration from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398270/9192223

Comment: You have to determine an end for your parts of substrings. If we determine . and space as separators, then you can use this pattern. (.{0,10})(?:\s|\.) https://regex101.com/r/I1nrb6/1

Comment: @hiren thanks, a lot of possible ways to solve the problem. But I'd like to use regex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might be a little complicated, maybe we could start with:

```
.{1,10}[^\s](?=\s|$)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/e7ckgq/1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = ".{1,10}[^\\s](?=\\s|$)";
final String string = "James has gone out for a meal.";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, remove all double spaces if exists and apply this regex.

```
.{1,11}(?:\s|$)|.{1,11}(?:[^\s]|$)
```

But I would use the split function and then 'for clause' calculating lengths.